# GoogleCloudMessaging withou play services

Tags: android, notifications, google-play-services, urbanairship.com

I am using [*Google Cloud Messaging*](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) in my app with the help of *Urban Airship*.

*Urban Airship* is doing the registering to GCM and my code is doing the receiving of the GCM messages.

My question is who can it be that my app and the notifications are working without *Google play services* installed on the device?

As you see, my app works but I am afraid of a future problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your device must have Google Play Services on it for you to be receiving notifications via Urban Airship, which uses GCM behind-the-scenes.

If that is an issue, consider alternative push gateways such as Pushy (https://pushy.me/) that do not depend on GCM / Google Play Services, establishing their own connection instead to receive push notifications.

Full disclosure - I am the Founder & CEO at Pushy.